# How can I change the vertical skip between main body text and footnote with the eledmac package?

Tags: footnotes, eledmac

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\patchcmd{\twocolfootfmtX}{\raggedright}{}{}{}
\foottwocolX{A}%
\let\footnote\footnoteA

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[2]\footnote{\blindtext[2]}\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

I tried with `\setlength{\skip\footins}{30pt}` before and after eledmac package without any result. Any solution?

Comment: Try: `\setlength{\skip\footinsA}{30pt}`.

Comment: See also doc, section 4.3.8 (`\prenotesX{30pt}` seems good).

Comment: Would be in my opinion good to mention, that `\patchcmd` is a macro from `etoolbox`, and that this is loaded under the hood by `eledmac`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers of jon and Robert are both right.

There is, anyway, a little difference between them:

- `\setlength{\skip\footinsA}{30pt}` will set the space before the footnotes of level A. So if in a specific page you have only a footnote of level B, you won't have the 30 pt space.
- `\prenotesX{30pt}` will set the space before all the footnotes. So if in a specific page you have only a footnote of level B, you will have the 30 pt space.

So you should use the second way in many case. Indeed, that is the only documented way, because of "hight level".